# Can this SQL be translated to LINQ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I am working with a quite tricky SQL-Query that I would like to translate to LINQ.

Do you think it is possible?

```
WITH ConditionalChecks AS (
    SELECT c.ItemId FROM ConditionalProperties c, Properties p
    WHERE c.PropertyId = p.Id AND c.IsChecked = 1 AND (

        (p.SystemName = 'eatable') OR
        (p.SystemName = 'diy')

    )
),

ConditionalCount AS (
    SELECT ItemId, Count(*) AS NumTrue FROM ConditionalChecks
    GROUP BY ItemId
),

ItemResult AS (
    SELECT * FROM ConditionalCount c, Items i
    WHERE c.ItemId = i.Id
)

SELECT * FROM ItemResult
WHERE NumTrue = 2
```

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ makes it easy to aggregate queries like this.

```
var conditionalChecksQuery = 
    from c in db.ConditionalProperties
    where c.IsChecked == 1  // or 'true', if boolean
    join p in db.Properties on c.PropertyId equals p.Id
    where p.SystemName == "eatable" || p.SystemName == "diy"
    select c.ItemId;

var conditionalCountQuery = 
    from c in conditionalChecksQuery
    group c by c.ItemId into cGrouped
    select new { ItemId = cGrouped.Key, NumTrue = cGrouped.Count() };

var itemResultQuery = 
    from c in conditionalCountQuery
    join i in db.Items on c.ItemId equals i.Id
    select new { Item = i, NumTrue = c.NumTrue };

var finalQuery =
    from result in itemResultQuery
    where result.NumTrue == 2
    select result;
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, that's exactly was I was looking for. I just learnt ALOT from this, thanks :)

Comment: Ben i have one doubt . If we are using LINQ we want to keep everything in separate obj and do the operation.So it will reduce the execution speed ,When compare with SQL Procedure?

Comment: SQL procedures have the advantage of plan-caching, but otherwise it should not be any slower to do this in LINQ. I'm not sure if you mean that the queries are executed one-by-one, but if so, they are not: only when the final query is enumerated over is the entire query translated to SQL and executed once.

Comment: No problem. Here is one of many articles on that feature, which is called 'deferred execution': http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work

```
Select * FROM (
    Select c.ItemID, Count(*) As NumTrue
    FROM ConditionalProperties c, Properties p
    WHERE c.PropertyId = p.Id AND c.IsChecked = 1 AND (
    (p.SystemName = 'eatable') OR
    (p.SystemName = 'diy')
    GROUP BY ItemID
) AS ConditionalCount 
INNER JOIN Items AS I
ON  ConditionalCount.ItemID = I.id
WHERE ConditionalCount.NumTrue = 2
```

This is SQL, don't know why I thought you were doing LINQ, and wanted SQL, but this is a much simpler form of the SQL that should do the exact same thing as your multiple queries.

Comment: It doesn't look like SQL I see, so I think my brain just switched it for some reason.  Weird.

Comment: That works, but it's just another way of writing the exact same SQL.

I'm looking for the LINQ translation :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess my brain shuts off on the weekend.  Anyway, maybe the simpler form of the SQL is easier to convert into LINQ.  Sorry, I'm not that familiar with LINQ, so I can't help you there.  I'm leaving this up so maybe another poster who's more fluent with LINQ can have an easier time converting the query to LINQ.